# running multiple macros when cells in a range are changed

Tags: vba, excel

bear with me, as I am a *complete* vba newbie and wrapping my head around what I already have has already taken me much longer than I care to admit.

I have a workbook with one master list "ITEMS" and several (up to 15) sub-tabs that grab information from the ITEMS sheet. I've been able to make this happen using buttons on each sub sheet which call this code:

```
Private Sub getNELL_Click()
Sheets("ITEMS").Range("A1:K400").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Sheets("ITEMS").Range("O1:O2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:K1") _
, Unique:=False
End Sub
```

This code successfully grabs each relevant row into the sheet each time I click the button, where each getX has a different name/criteria range (getRILEY, getELLE etc.)

But what I'm looking to do next is to have these macros run automatically when any cell in the G column of the ITEMS sheet is changed. In plain text, what I need is:

```
When [Any Cell in Column G] in Sheet("ITEMS") is changed
Run getNELL, getRiley, getELLE (x15 different macros)
```

[here's my file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fs3zl79s99c87y/sheet%20copy.xlsm?dl=0) with all the sheet (*sic*) in it.

EDIT:

and it's *done*!

moving the macros to a module instead of in each individual sheet, making them public and removing the _Click, along with the following code worked the magic I needed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim KeyCells As Range
 Set KeyCells = Range("G2:G400")

 If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
 Is Nothing Then

  getNELL
  getMIKA
  getRILEY
  getJANNA
  getWOO
  getELLE
  getMK
  getLAURA
  getFLIPSE
  getJENN
  getCRIS

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, use [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612) as a resource for triggering an event when cells change. That's usually just in the subroutine declaration.

For the code, change all of your private subs to public subs by replacing "private" with "public". Then in your subroutine list the subroutines to call:

>

> Subx
>
> > Suby
>
> Subz
>
> > end sub

Sorry the answer isn't super detailed as I am typing from my phone. Also, those sub examples should each be on their own line. I can't seem to change that on here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Then in your subroutine list the subroutines to call"

Comment: So you can create a macro that calls the other macros. If you create the macro that runs on a cell value changing, just put the other macro names in the code. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

you have already created filter criteria in ITEM sheet (grey highlighted)
so create one mapping for what sheet needs what criteria range in INDEX sheet
e.g.

```
SheetName   Criteria Mapping
nell        O1:O2
mika        P1:P2
riley       Q1:Q2
janna       R1:R2
woo         S1:S2
elle        O3:O4
mk          P3:P4
laura       Q3:Q4
flipse      R3:R4
jenn        S3:S4
cris        O5:O6
```

Add this code in a Module

```
Public Sub pGet_Data(ByVal SheetName As Worksheet, ByVal CriteriaRng As Range)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ITEMS").Range("A1:K400").AdvancedFilter _
                    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                    CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRng, _
                    CopyToRange:=SheetName.Range("A1:K1"), _
                    Unique:=False

End Sub
```

And in Thisworkbook Module add given code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCriteriaRange    As Range
    Dim rngOneMap           As Range
    Dim wksSheet            As Worksheet

    If Sh.Name = "ITEMS" And Target.Column = 7 Then
        Set rngCriteriaRange = Sh.Range("W6:X16") '<--you can make it dynamic

        For Each rngOneMap In rngCriteriaRange.Rows
            Set wksSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rngOneMap.Cells(1, 1).Value)
            Application.StatusBar = "Updating [" & wksSheet & "] Sheet"
            Call pGet_Data(wksSheet, wksSheet.Range(rngOneMap.Cells(1, 2).Value))
        Next rngOneMap
    End If

    MsgBox "Sheets has been updated.", vbOKOnly, "Be Happy..."

ClearMemory:
    Set rngCriteriaRange = Nothing
    Set rngOneMap = Nothing
    Set wksSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

I think this will resolve what you are looking for... :)

Comment: I found the help I needed, but I really appreciate your reply all the same. :)